# Using Evaluate to compare date type and int type

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to use the Evaluate function in Excel (office2010) to compare date types but keep running into the wall. Appreciate any help.
Below is the subroutine used

```
Sub tyrEval()
Dim myDate1 As Date
Dim myDate2 As Date
Dim myInt1 As Integer
Dim myInt2 As Integer
Dim myBool As Boolean
Dim myBool1 As Boolean
Dim myBool2 As Boolean
Dim myOperator As String
myDate1 = CDate("3/13/2016 01:04:53 am")
myDate2 = CDate("3/13/2016 12:23:37 am")
myOperator = ">"
myInt1 = 7
myInt2 = 6

myBool = Evaluate(myInt1 & myOperator & myInt2)
myBool1 = Evaluate(myDate1 & myOperator & myDate2)
myBool2 = myDate1 > myDate2

'myBool1 = Evaluate(Chr(34) & myDate1 & Chr(34) & myOperator & Chr(34) & myDate2 & Chr(34)) - working but wrong answer
'myBool1 = Evaluate(Chr(34) & "myDate1" & Chr(34) & myOperator & Chr(34) & "myDate2" & Chr(34)) - working but wrong answer    
'myBool = Evaluate(myInt1 & myOperator & myInt2) - works    
End Sub
```

When I step through the code I get a 'Type Mismatch error' at

```
myBool1 = Evaluate(myDate1 & myOperator & myDate2)
```

The myBool and myBool2 are getting results as expected.  I cant figure out my error in the myBool1 statement.  I have tried adding chr(34) across various locations but it dint get me anywhere.  The commented-out line shows one such variation which came up as myBool1 ='FALSE' which I'm guessing that the compare operation is being done as a string type and not as a date type.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your date was in the format `dd/mm/yyyy` then the evaluate expression would have worked but it is in the format `m/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm`

Since we know that Excel stores the date and time in number format, simply try this and it will work :)

```
Dim myDate1 As Double
Dim myDate2 As Double
```

Comment: Since there are times involved, using a Double would be better.

Comment: Good idea! :) Done

Comment: `Double` would also facilitate comparing mixed *date/times*